# Is this an elegant way to initialize a variable for the first iteration of a loop?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, variable-initialization

This is a C program that copies its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank. I don't know what is the best way to proceed when the program starts and there isn't a previous value yet.

I have come up with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

        int actual, previous = -1;

        while((actual = getchar()) != EOF) {
                if(!(previous == ' ' && actual == ' ')) {
                        putchar(actual);
                        previous = actual;
                }
        }
}
```

This works, however I was taught that you should not initialize a variable to a random value. Another option would be to use a do-while loop, but then if the program gets an empty file it will go through the if statement for nothing.

Comment: Now that I'm here, I would also like to read your opinion on whether the way of writing the expression in the if statement is the best, as there are many ways of doing it, like applying D'Morgan's law to the current expression.

Comment: Note that `void main()` is only valid on MS Windows (at least, for mainstream hosted implementations).  Everywhere else, [the return type should be `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Comment: I think the code is OK.  You could apply De Morgan's theorems to write `if (previous != ' ' || actual != ' ') { … }`.  Neither is particularly easy to read.  An extra variable seems unnecessary.  You could use `EOF` instead of `-1` — though on most systems, the result would be the same.  But `getchar()` returns either a positive value (`unsigned char` converted to `int`) or `EOF`, so there's no risk of confusion since you're correct using `int` for `previous` and `actual`.

Comment: An empty file should yield EOF, so the if-statement should not run

Comment: Problem: `previous=actual` should be outside of `if` otherwise previous always remains space character.

Comment: "however I was taught that you should not initialize a variable to a random value." --> Yes, instead `previous = EOF;`.

Comment: hmmm.... I don't see why this is closed as opinion-based. The initial value of `previous` is important for the program behavior. In other words... the initial values depends on what you want to happen if the first input is a space. Nothing opinion-based about that.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the first input is a space? Do you want the program to print a space? Or do you want the program to ignore that input? That's what determines the initialization of `previous` to be either a space or something different than space.

Comment: A much nicer initial value for `previous` would be `EOF` not `-1`.  ISO C requires `EOF` to be a negative value, not specifically -1, so by using -1, you could be introducing a second value that is not equal to a valid byte. Why have two?

Comment: @fukanchik — the code as written in the question works correctly (at least if `void main()` is changed to `int main(void)`).  The `previous = actual;` assignment does not need to be outside the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I would just set a boolean flag that can be checked and if we're not on the first iteration and the actual and previous character are both spaces we can skip printing the character and updating the previous char and setting the `first_char` flag to `false`.

This way `previous` is never used before being initialized.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    bool first_char = true;
    int actual, previous;

    while ((actual = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (!first_char && previous == ' ' && actual == ' ') {
            continue;
        } 
        
        putchar(actual);
        previous = actual;
        first_char = false;
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a warning that "`previous` may be used uninitialized in this function".  I'm not entirely sure it's a valid warning, but GCC 11.2.0 generates it.

Comment: I'm not convinced a third variable is an improvement over the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `in_spaces` variable to keep track of whether you are reading input while in a section of spaces or not. `in_spaces` is initialized to `0`, or false, since you don't start out reading from a group of spaces.

If you are in a group of spaces and a space is read, just continue and read the next character. Otherwise you always want to print the character. If that character is a space, you are in a group of spaces so `in_spaces` should be set to `1`, or true. Otherwise that character is not a space so you are not in a group of spaces and `in_space` should be set to `0`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int in_spaces = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (in_spaces && c == ' ') continue;
        putchar(c);
        if (c == ' '){
            in_spaces = 1;
        } else {
            in_spaces = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And, as bonus, you can initialize *in_spaces* to 1, to trim the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, `void main()` is ill advised...

If your concern is repeated spaces (0x20), then `-1` is arbitrary. Equally arbitrary, but less jarring would be `0`. (In fact, you could use any value except 0x20!)...

Collapsing your code into a `for()` loop reduces the amount of code. A helpful comment is always helpful. The testing code supplies several strings testing leading, trailing and mid-string runs of repeated SP's.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test( char *str ) {
    putchar( '"' );
    for( int ch, prvCh = ~' '; (ch = *str++) != '\0'; prvCh = ch )
        if( prvCh != ' ' || ch != ' ' ) // suppress successive SP's as single.
            putchar( ch );
    putchar( '"' );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) {
    test( "abc     def" ); // test middle SPSPSP
    test( " abc    def " ); // test single leading & trailing SP
    test( "   abc  def   " ); // test multiple leading & trailing SPs
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"abc def"
" abc def "
" abc def "
```

Note the initialisation of `prvCh` as `~' '`... Uncommon notation that expresses "a value that is not an SP".

The changes to use `getchar()` and `EOF` should be obvious and easy.

Comment: `!' '` is a weird way of writing `0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Obviously, I've been somewhat distracted... Have "improved" the answer. (It's always the _obvious_ that is anything but...)